# How do you define a hash function in Python

Tags: python, hash, hashmap, hashtable, hashcode

I was watching a video on [*Hash Table*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPo-M8bzRrc), and the professor clearly said:
[image]

Now suppose I am using `Python` to add million values into my hash table.

Code:

```
dictionary = {}
for i in xrange(1000000):
    dictionary[i] = ''

dictionary = {}
for i in ['A', 'B', 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 'Hi']:
    dictionary[i] = ''
```

How do you calculate a `hash function` here? Since you are constantly adding elements into the dictionary, does the `hash function` continuously change based on total number of elements? Or The `hash function` is decided once before inserting all the elements?

Since my program doesn't know what all values might come in the dictionary, how do we decide the hash function here? My list of values can be anything here not just numbers.

Comment: Which __hash__ function are you referring to, that of the class that you'll be using as the key to your table, or of the hash table class itself?

Comment: The one that can magically generate a `unique key` for each value in my list.

Comment: Hash functions don't do that.

Comment: Could you elaborate more !

Answer (score 2):

Keys for Dictionaries in Python can be an immutable data type, so long as it supports hashing.  As an example,

```
X = 1
print(X.__hash__())
```

This shows the unique hash value for the value of this object.  Each key within a Dictionary MUST be unique, that's why you cannot have duplicate keys.

```
Y = "1"
print(Y.__hash__())
```

All hash values within Python are integral, irregardless of the data type you're hashing.

Comment: Indent your lines 4 extra spaces for code formatting.

Comment: I was fighting it on my iPad, logged into my Macbook ~ Thanks @user2357112

Comment: Can you say that two different values will not generate the same hash?

Comment: There must be some function hash function which is generating all these integral value right?

Comment: For the most part, correct!  I would have to dig deep into the implementation for exactly how they implement hash, but it should provide unique values for most data types you would run across

Comment: Check out this link: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html - They talk about Custom Hash functions and other related things